# How to show declined meeting on Outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

I declined a recurring meeting invitation in Outlook 2007 to let the organizer know I am unable to attend, which will be true most of the time. But there will be rare occasions when I could attend so I would like to have this declined meeting show up on my calendar. Currently, it is sitting in my Deleted Items folder and I find no way to move/copy/transfer it to the calendar. Also, contrary to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/72762/how-to-get-back-a-declined-outlook-invitation) -- I do not even see an option to redo my accept/decline choice.

Comment: Is it possible to create a manual appointment for yourself with the reminders, and then simply dismiss these when you can't attend?  I personally have had trouble making Outlook 2007 do the right thing in calendar events too.  Maybe a work around is the best way to get what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My needs are a little different.  If I think there's any chance I may be able to attend I will reply as tentative.  If I know I won't attend I do decline, so my true free/busy status shows on our shared calendar.  Most declined meetings I can just keep track of on the shared calendar, but for some it's important to me to know when certain things are being done or when certain people will be busy.  I want these in my own calendar because I sync it with my smartphone and I want to see them when I'm not at my desk.  Keeping meeting requests in the inbox just clutters the box, risks accidental deletion, and seems in general no way to run a railroad.  Seems to me there ought to be a better way, even if it's only some kind of macro that makes a copy of the meeting in my own calendar.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should just accept as tentative.

Answer (score 4):

What I was able to do here, is decline the invite in the calendar view, then find the invite (either in the deleted folder, or in my case it was still in my inbox for some reason), and tentatively accept but choose the option not to send to a response.

Answer (score 2):

I think simple copy-paste is good enough.

- Before declining, click the appointment in calendar and with copy+paste you'll get a private appointment.
- Then you may decline the original leaving you with the copy in your calendar.
- If you prefer, you may change the copy to show as free in your calendar.

Some limitations are that you won't receive updates and you can't later on accept the copy but you'll have to find the original invitation from deleted items.

Answer (score 2):

I receive meeting requests on behalf on my C-level executive.  When I decline a meeting for him that he cannot attend, I respond using “tentative”, change the word “tentative” to read “decline” and send.  It stays on his calendar and the organizer receives a visual that the request was declined.  I then go into the meeting on his calendar and change the availability to free.  This allows us to receive updates (date/time), shows him that I declined the request and if his availability changes, I can ‘accept’ the request for his attendance.

I would love to see this option in future versions.

Comment: This workflow makes me cringe, but seems the optimal way to work right now +1

Answer (score 1):

If you do "drag the declined request from the deleted items folder into the calendar" (tried in Outlook 2010) it will change "declined" to "accepted" and notify the mtg organizer.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this works, go to > | options | email options | advanced
email options| Delete meeting request from Inbox when responding.

Answer (score 0):

Works in 2010: drag the declined request from the deleted items folder into the calendar.

Why the hell you can't just set it to do this is beyond me but so is the fact that people choose to use Outlook. If you click on the calendar in Outlook you will see that it is now 2013.